# Getting the IP of a VMware ESX host through vijava

Tags: vmware, vsphere, esxi, esx

I'm trying to get the IP of the hostsystems managed by our  vCenter. the `host.getName()` only returns the DNS name of the host. What might be a way to get the IP address that you get when you ping the given host name?

Comment: could you be more specific about the code you used? (viijava property). Have you checked [HostIpConfig](http://vijava.sourceforge.net/vSphereAPIDoc/ver51/ReferenceGuide/) values  ?

Answer (score 1):

For those who still havig this issue, you can get the host public ip using vijava, in this way :

```
String hostIp = host.getConfig().getNetwork().getVnic()[0].getSpec().getIp().getIpAddress();
```

vijava 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

host.getConfig().getNetwork().getVnic().spec.getIp().getIpAddress()

I've used something like this earlier and it worked.